# Why can't I extract with-redefs into a seperate function?

Tags: clojure

I have a function that I would like to test.

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [port (Integer/parseInt (or (first args) "8080"))]
    (run-jetty
      app
      {:port port})))
```

I need to mock away `run-jetty` for obvious reasons, so I use `with-redefs` to verify that the correct args are passed. This works great.

```
(it "should overide the port with first arg"
        (with-redefs [run-jetty (fn [handler opts] [handler opts])]
            (should= 8081 (jetty-port (underTest/-main "8081")))))
```

I'd like to extract the `with-redefs` call since I use it in a few more tests, so I tried this:

```
(defn mock-jetty
  [test]
  (with-redefs [run-jetty (fn [handler args] [handler args])] test))

(describe "The app"
  (it "should default to port 8080"
      (mock-jetty
        (should= 8080 (jetty-port (underTest/-main))))))
```

This test calls the real `run-jetty` function and starts a server. Why does this happen?

**EDIT**

Changing extraction to a macro:

```
(defmacro mock-jetty
  [someTest]
  `(with-redefs [run-jetty (fn [handler args] [handler args])] ~someTest))

(describe "The app"
  (it "should default to port 8080"
      (mock-jetty
        (should= 8080 (jetty-port (underTest/-main))))))
```

throws this exception:
`Can't use qualified name as parameter: boost-bin.handler-test/handler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can guess, that it is connected with the fact that `with-redefs` is a macro. So when you call it straight in code, it executes `test` body in context of redefs, while when you move it out to the function, the body `(should= 8080 (jetty-port (underTest/-main)))` is being executed before being passed to macro (as it always happens to functions' params)

To make it work, you could rewrite `mock-jetty` as a macro:

```
(defmacro mock-jetty
  [test]
  `(with-redefs [run-jetty (fn [handler# args#] [handler# args#])] ~test))
```

I'm pretty sure it would help

Comment: This throws an exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't use qualified name as parameter: boost-bin.handler-test/handler`. Do I need to quote the function params?

Comment: right, i've forgotten about quoting of function params. Better use gensyms for that. Updated my post

Comment: Not sure if i should make another question for this, but what was causing the exception?

Comment: Sorry, away from my laptop. You can search SO by the exception text. There should be some similar questions with answers

Comment: [Link to explanation](http://osdir.com/ml/java.clojure.user/2008-03/msg00108.html)